# Converting roman numerals into numbers using find statement in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am having trouble converting roman numerals into normal numbers in C++, the code works to a degree however it if the numerals (XIV 14 or LIV etc) are entered it will out put 15 or 55.
I have tried to implement the find statement however I have no real idea how to use it to solve my problem, here is a copy of my code so far;

```
int convNum;
int total = 0;
string romanNum;
const string units [10]= {"0","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"};
const string tens [10]= {"0","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC"};
const string hundreds [10]= {"0","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM"};
const string thousands [4]= {"0","M","MM","MMM"};
string input;

while(!cin.eof()){
    cin>>romanNum;
    if(cin.fail()){
        break;
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i<romanNum.length(); i++){
            romanNum[i]=toupper(romanNum[i]);
        }
        for(int y=3; y > 0; y--){
           if(romanNum.find(thousands[y])!= string::npos){
               total += y*1000;
               input.erase(0,thousands[y].length());
               break;
            }
        }
        for(int y=9; y > 0; y--){
           if(romanNum.find(hundreds[y])!= string::npos){
               total += y*100;
               input.erase(0,hundreds[y].length());
               break;
            }
        }
        for(int y=9; y > 0; y--){
           if(romanNum.find(tens[y])!= string::npos){
               total += y*10;
               input.erase(0,tens[y].length());
               break;
            } 
        }
        for(int y=9; y > 0; y--){
           if(romanNum.find(units[y])!= string::npos){
               total += y;
               input.erase(0,units[y].length());
               break;
            }
        }
        cout << total << endl;
        total = 0;
           }

        for(int k=0; k < romanNum.length(); k++){
            input[k] = romanNum[k];
        }


        }     


return 0;
```

}

If anyone can help me with this it will be greatly appreciated, as I am a beginner and coding this amount of C++ code took me around 2 weeks to code.

Comment: Are you allowed to implement this using a different technique? For me, the first one that comes to mind is a state machine.

Comment: No I don't think so, (sorry I have no idea what state machine even is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two problems:

First, when you are erasing the numerals that you found, you are erasing from the `input` string, not your `romanNum` string. You should be erasing from the `romanNum` string instead:

```
romanNum.erase(0, thousands[y].length());
```

Second, it looks like you are searching for results anywhere in the string, not just at the beginning. So in the example of "LIV", when you are searching through the `units` list, it will find "V" at the end of the list, adding 5, then it will erase the "I" (because it always erases from the front of the list. One solution to this is to only accept results that are at the beginning of your current string. So, instead of doing `!= string::npos`, just do `== 0`:

```
if (romanNum.find(thousands[y]) == 0) {
```

Comment: ok, and I should amend that for all my for statements right? (I know it's an obvious question, I am just not thinking straight at the moment)

Comment: Never mind about that last reply of mine, I implemented the changes and it looks like its working thank you for your help with it.

Answer (score 0):

I will not do the debugging for you, I'll just identify three issues.

1. You're searching in `romanNum` but you're erasing the characters you found from `input`.  Shouldn't that be the same string?
2. You're getting 15 because the first `unit` string found in the number is `"V"`, not `"IV"`, as you're iterating in reverse order.
3. Shouldn't you be looking for strings that are *a prefix* of your number?  Not anywhere in it.  You would want the `find` method to return 0, not anything else.